# How I can remove element from each row?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

[image]

The Above one is my data, I want to delete the 'International Movies' and 'Independent Movies' from all of the rows.

[image]

If I see the first row of this data it comes up in string format along with ',' separation. If I use the split(',') to convert each str of each row to a list, it splits in this way.

[image]

I checked the first row of this;

[image]

There is space ==> ' International Movies'
But if this comes at zeroth element then it has no space, check on certain rows. check below ==> 'International Movies'

[image]

I have to use two if loop if ' International Movies' occurs then delete this, and if 'International Movies' occurs delete this using pop. But it is not working in my case.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Check this Google Colab, everything is there. You can show me there.**

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lq68InH5gBt2T6G1LkWMrRNHzljxlifw?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post codes, errors and output as text and not images.

Answer (score 0):

you can try re based split for this instead of splitting on ','.

You can read about re here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re
df.Genre.apply(
    lambda x: re.split('\s*,\s*', x)).apply(
        lambda x: [e for e in x if e not in [ 'International Movies', 'Independent Movies']])
```

Comment: you can also use `lambda x: [x.strip() for x in x.split(",")]` as first lambda instead of using re. It will remove all leading and trailing spaces in splitted values.

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid `.apply` when possible because it is considerably slow with large datasets. Instead use another `pandas` tools. In this case, this is achievable with [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.Genre.str.replace(", (International|Independent) Movies", '')
```

Note that I am taking advantage of the fact that the target strings are (apparently) only in the center or at the end.